# Skip item when performing map in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, try-catch, swift2

I'm applying a map to a dictionary that has a `try` in it. I'd like to skip the iteration if the mapped item is invalid.

For example:

```
func doSomething<T: MyType>() -> [T]
    dictionaries.map({
        try? anotherFunc($0) // Want to keep non-optionals in array, how to skip?
    })
}
```

In the above sample, if `anotherFunc` returns `nil`, how to escape the current iteration and move on to the next? That way, it would not contain the items that are `nil`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just replace `map()` by `flatMap()`:

```
extension SequenceType {
    /// Returns an `Array` containing the non-nil results of mapping
    /// `transform` over `self`.
    ///
    /// - Complexity: O(*M* + *N*), where *M* is the length of `self`
    ///   and *N* is the length of the result.
    @warn_unused_result
    public func flatMap<T>(@noescape transform: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> T?) rethrows -> [T]
}
```

`try? ...` returns `nil` if the call throws an error, so those
elements will be omitted in the result.

A self-contained example just for demonstration purposes:

```
enum MyError : ErrorType {
    case DivisionByZeroError
}

func inverse(x : Double) throws -> Double {
    guard x != 0 else {
        throw MyError.DivisionByZeroError
    }
    return 1.0/x
}

let values = [ 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 4.0 ]
let result = values.flatMap {
    try? inverse($0)
}
print(result) // [1.0, 0.5, 0.25]
```

For **Swift 3,** replace `ErrorType` by `Error`.

For **Swift 4** use `compactMap`

Comment: Thank for allowing me to discover `flatMap`! I just noticed it doesn't work with dictionaries tho.

Comment: @TruMan1: I am pretty sure that it does. Both `map` and `flatMap` can be applied to a  dictionary. The closure is called with key/value as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to skip a certain index when using `compactMap`:

```
yourCollectionArray.enumerated().compactMap { index, element in
    // Skips the first 3 elements
    if index < 3 { return nil }


    // Return your transformed type here..
}
```